# Bootstrap images won't be side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a project for school and I'm basically creating a library of stories for these medically fragile children. I am wanting to basically create a preview window 3 across the width of the page and then as many down as we have stories. Right now I have the box exactly how I want it the thing is that I can't get the other box to go beside it. I don't know why this is. Here is my code and sorry its so messy, especially the bottom part where I am talking about.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
<title>Hope's Seed</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Kanit|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<style>

.navbar-brand{
 font-size: 50px;
 color:white;
 font-family:'Lobster';
 height: 100%;
}

#list{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Abel';
 font-size: 30px;
}

p{
 font-family: 'Kanit';
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar{
  padding-top:20px;
}

#alone{
 background-image: url(/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/alone.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.navbar-header{
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

#three{
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#box-wrapper{
  background-image: url(/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagethree.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#logo{
padding:0px;
}

.middleimage{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:275px;
  left: 485px;
  color: white;
  font-family:'Abel';
}

.bottomimage{
 font-size: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top:175px;
 left: 43%;
 color: black;
 font-family:'Abel';
}

.story1
{
  background-color: #d9d7d6;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  }

.info1{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#p1{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.story2{
  background-color: #d9d7d6;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  top:-300;
  }

.info2{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#p2{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#54E10D;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/logo.png"
  style="height:94px; width: 115px;" id="logo"></a>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand "href="hopesseed-homepage.html" id="list">Hope's Seed</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
          <li class="active"><a href="hopesseed-homepage." id="list">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html" id="list">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" id="list">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="donate.html" id="list">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="sponsors.html" id="list">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="stories.html" id="list">Stories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
<div class="jumbotron" id="box-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
        <div class="text-uppercase middleimage">
          <h1>You're Not Alone</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <br>
  <br>
<div class="container">
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laorum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="jumbotron" id="alone">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-uppercase bottomimage">
     <h1> Stories </h1>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row container-fluid">
<div class="story1 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <a href="story-number-one.html">
  <img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagetwo.jpg" style="max-height:100%; max-width:270px;" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="info1">
      <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;"> Name: John AppleSeed </h1>
      <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;"> Age: 12 years old </h1>
    </div>
  <p id="p1">ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol
    upt cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</a>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="story2 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <a href="story-number-two.html">
  <img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagetwo.jpg" style="max-height:100%; max-width:270px;" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="info2">
      <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Name: John AppleSeed </h1>
      <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Age: 12 years old </h1>
    </div>
  <p id="p2">ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol
    upt cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
<title>Hope's Seed</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Kanit|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<style>

.navbar-brand{
 font-size: 50px;
 color:white;
 font-family:'Lobster';
 height: 100%;
}

#list{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Abel';
 font-size: 30px;
}

p{
 font-family: 'Kanit';
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar{
  padding-top:20px;
}

#alone{
 background-image: url(/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/alone.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.navbar-header{
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

#three{
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#box-wrapper{
  background-image: url(/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagethree.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#logo{
padding:0px;
}

.middleimage{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:275px;
  left: 485px;
  color: white;
  font-family:'Abel';
}

.bottomimage{
 font-size: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top:175px;
 left: 43%;
 color: black;
 font-family:'Abel';
}

.story1
{
  background-color: #d9d7d6;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  }

.info1{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#p1{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.story2{
  background-color: #d9d7d6;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  top:-300;
  }

.info2{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#p2{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#54E10D;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/logo.png"
  style="height:94px; width: 115px;" id="logo"></a>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand "href="hopesseed-homepage.html" id="list">Hope's Seed</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
          <li class="active"><a href="hopesseed-homepage." id="list">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html" id="list">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" id="list">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="donate.html" id="list">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="sponsors.html" id="list">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="stories.html" id="list">Stories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="box-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
        <div class="text-uppercase middleimage">
          <h1 style="color:gray;">You're Not Alone</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laorum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="alone">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-uppercase bottomimage">
     <h1> Stories </h1>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="story1 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="story-number-one.html">
    <img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagetwo.jpg" style="max-height:100%; max-width:270px;" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="info1">
     <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;"> Name: John AppleSeed </h1>
     <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;"> Age: 12 years old </h1>
   </div>
    <p id="p1">ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol
   upt cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </a>
  </div>

  <div class="story1 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="story-number-two.html">
    <img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagetwo.jpg" style="max-height:100%; max-width:270px;" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="info2">
     <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Name: John AppleSeed </h1>
     <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Age: 12 years old </h1>
   </div>
    <p id="p2">ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol
   upt cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class="story1 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="story-number-two.html">
    <img src="/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagetwo.jpg" style="max-height:100%; max-width:270px;" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="info2">
     <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Name: John AppleSeed </h1>
     <h1 style="font-size:15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Age: 12 years old </h1>
   </div>
    <p id="p2">ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in vol
   upt cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    </a>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, i have prepare one basic solution for you. 
Hope it's works for you! If you still having any doubt then plz do ask me. Thank you